# remove symbols from text field with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have function to remove symbols from a text. How to keep commas and dots ( . , ) in text field? Becouse at the moment function remove everithing who is not digits

```
$('.numbersOnly').bind("keyup paste", function(){
        setTimeout(jQuery.proxy(function() {
            this.val(this.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));
        }, $(this)), 0);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
this.val(this.val().replace(/[^0-9,.]/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code :-

```
$('.numbersOnly').bind("keyup paste", function(){
        setTimeout(jQuery.proxy(function() {
             this.val(this.val().replace(/[^0-9.,]/g, '')
        }, $(this)), 0);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
$('.numbersOnly').bind("keyup paste", function(){
        setTimeout(jQuery.proxy(function() {
            this.val(this.val().replace(/[^0-9\.\,]/g, ''));
        }, $(this)), 0);

});
```